# Apply a function from a specific R package to all files in folder

Tags: r

I have a large table that I am reading into R as a data frame. After ordering and subsetting the df I break it into a list using the split() function. I then write that list out as individual text files. I am now reading the individual .txt files back into R so that I can determine the effectiveSize (from the coda package) of each file that does not lack Energy values. However I don't think this is the most efficient method. In any case, is there a way that I could apply the effectiveSize to each individual file or element of the list? When I test the effectiveSize function on one of the output files - effectiveSize(ASP29A[,3]) it works fine. But that's only one of 102 files/elements.

The original ordered data frame looks like this;

```
Chain  Res    Energy
 A    ALA28  -1.8046
 A    ALA28  -2.1910
 A    ALA28  -1.8403
 A    ALA28  -2.1813
 A    ALA28  -2.3693
 A    ALA28  -2.2808
```

I hope this is clear.

As a list, the data looks like

```
$ C.017500:'data.frame':    6003 obs. of  3 variables:
..$ Chain : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
..$ Res   : chr [1:6003] "017500" "017500" "017500" "017500" ...
..$ Energy: num [1:6003] -37 -33.8 -34.7 -35.4 -35 ...

$ A.ALA28 :'data.frame':    6003 obs. of  3 variables:
..$ Chain : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..$ Res   : chr [1:6003] "ALA28" "ALA28" "ALA28" "ALA28" ...
..$ Energy: num [1:6003] -1.8 -2.19 -1.84 -2.37 -2.18 ...
```

And so on through 102 elements.

Comment: Essentially, I have a long list of data frames.

Comment: `sapply(yourlistofdataframes, function(x) effectiveSize(x[,"Energy"]))`

Comment: When I use this command I get "Error in model.frame.default(formula = x[, i] ~ z, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'z') "

Comment: It hard to know, but  using nicos answer: it looks like you would do: `yourlistofdataframes <- lapply(file.list, read.table, header=T)` ; and then the `sapply` function above. Perhaps you could show the first oouple ofr rows of the new read in data (rather than original)

Comment: hi user20650 I added some of the list above.

Comment: hi @user20650 I added some of the elements to the list above.

Comment: Thanks D.A. . I dont see why the `sapply` above doesnt work (or nicos code below) Try with this reproducible example: `lst <- setNames(replicate(10, list(data.frame(Chain=sample(letters[1:3], 50, T), Energy=rnorm(50, 0, 20)))), letters[1:10]) ; sapply(lst, function(x) coda::effectiveSize(x["Energy"]))`

Comment: Hello!! This is reproducible. My data frames however are not the same length. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Great stuff ... what was wrong .. one of our dataframes had zero rows??

Comment: I dropped the unused levels suggested by the error and combined the chain and res information into 1 so that the data was easier to work with.

Comment: Just one more thing, can you tell me if the sapply(lst, sd) works for you? it doesn't work for me @user20650

Comment: No, it doesn't work... but it shouldnt. You are trying to take the `sd` of a `data.frame`, which doesnt work. Try `sd(mtcars)`. To get it to work you need to select the column that you want to take the `sd` of, in much the same way as the `effectiveSize` `sapply` above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

- Read the file list using:

  ```
  setwd("path/to/files/")
  file.list <- dir(pattern = "txt$")
  ```

  The `pattern` bit is optional, but it can help you filtering only some files.
- Use `sapply` to run whatever function you want

  ```
  res <- sapply(file.list, yourfunction)
  ```

For instance, to know the file size of the files you could use:

```
res <- sapply(file.list, file.size)
```

You may want to create function to call `effectiveSize`, such as:

```
eff.size <- function(filename)
      {
      data <- read.table(filename)
      # <do something here with the data as needed>
      res <- effectiveSize(<appropriate parameters>)

      # return the result
      res
      }
```

Then call

```
 res <- sapply(file.list, eff.size)
```

Comment: Minor comments: the pattern here will find files with txt anywhere in the filename. You might want to consider `"\\.txt$"` which will restrict it to those ending .txt. You could also consider using `list.files("path", pattern = "\\.txt$, full.names = TRUE)` which avoids having to change the working directory.

Comment: This method seems to list the names of the files. I have already directed R to the list of files and gotten R to read each file. The problem is that now when I call sapply(file.list, effectiveSize(file.list[,3])) I get an error stating that  there is an incorrect number of dimensions when I don't think that's the case. Same problem happens if I use effectiveSize(file.list$Energy).

Comment: @NickK  I specifically avoided using path in the `dir` call, because otherwise I would have to prepend it to the file name in the `sapply` call.

Comment: @nico not using full.names = TRUE

Comment: @D.A.Ragland you should not call sapply like that. Rather `sapply(file.list, effective.Size)`

Comment: @NickK ops, sorry, did not see that :)

Comment: Should I define effective.Size first? because the function is effectiveSize(x)

Comment: @D.A.Ragland I am not quite sure about what the `effectivesize` function does, or what it expects. `sapply` will pass each file name to the function you put as a parameter. So, in this case it is passing the file name to `effectiveSize` (which, indeed may not be what you need). Maybe you want to create an helper function which gets the file name, reads the content of the file, then calls `effectiveSize` with the appropriate parameter.

Comment: ahhh. ok. that sounds like a plan. Any tips on how to create this helper function? I thought reading in all the files would do the trick.

Comment: @D.A.Ragland added an example of that!